# How to increase Expiration time for Aws s3 link created by using getSignedUrl method

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have a scenario where i need to make the expiration url forever, I am using getSignedUrl method from AWS S3, in my case link is getting expired after some default time, i want to make it accessible any poinyt of time in future.

Comment: You can not make it a non-expiring link. though you can prolong the expiration time up to 7 days

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it last more than one week:

> A presigned URL can be valid for a maximum of seven days because the
>   signing key you use in signature calculation is valid for up to seven
>   days.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html